# Nokogiri colocar tags com separação

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
teste = Nokogiri::XML::DocumentFragment.parse("")
Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with( teste ){ |x|  
    x.exemplo "teste xml"
}
puts teste.to_xml
```

Mensagem que imprimi

```
<exemplo>teste xml</exemplo>
```

Mensagem que desejada

```
<ns:exemplo>teste xml</ns:exemplo>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que entendi, você quer utilizar namespaces(as tags com separação). Um namespace precisa ser declarado associado a uma URI(Uniforme Resource Identifier). Se precisar de uma explicação mais detalhada pode encontrar em: https://imasters.com.br/artigo/161/dotnet/entendendo-namespaces/?trace=1519021197&source=single

Você pode criar um namespace com a gem Nokogiri como exemplo abaixo:

```
require 'nokogiri'

NAMESPACES = {
  "xmlns:ns"  => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",
  "xmlns:ns2" => "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
}

ex = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new { |xml|
  xml['ns'].exemplo(NAMESPACES) do
    xml.tagNamespace1 "Conteudo"
  end
}
puts ex.to_xml
```

Comment: Eu já resolvi este problema, mais o código esta correto. O interessante é que se querer usar a tag ns2,  xml['ns2'].tagNamespace1 "Conteudo"